# conflicting declaration error

Tags: c++, compilacion

Me sale este error cuando compilo mi programa:
"error: conflicting declaration 'AplicacionRobot Code'"

el archivo .h:

```
class AplicacionRobot: public Robots
{
     public:
          string Uso;
          AplicacionRobot(string);
};
```

el archivo .cpp:

```
AplicacionRobot::AplicacionRobot(string Uso)
{
    cout<<"Robot utilizado para "<<Uso<<endl;
}
```

En la función main():

```
string Code;
cout<<"Para que se va a usar el robot? ";
cin>>Code;
AplicacionRobot(Code);
```

Gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo estas haciendo de manera incorrecta. El compilador no es magia, tiene que poder entender que es lo que quieres hacer. De heho tampoco yo lo entinedo pero supongo que estas tratando de crear un `AplicationRobot`.

Cambia:

```
    AplicacionRobot(Code);
```

Por:

```
    AplicacionRobot robot = AplicacionRobot(Code);
```

O por:

```
    AplicacionRobot robot(Code);
```